# Can I Create ko observable object from JSON

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a json string created on the server. Can I create a new, observable structured object without having defined its observable properties in jscript first. I have a var defined:

```
var viewModel;
```

With the jsonString returned from ajax call I use:

> viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonString);

When I `ko.applyBindings` - it throws a can't find observable object error.

I do not see any properties in the viewModel. What am I missing?

Comment: We're going to need more code than that to be able to help you. Can you post what the JSON looks like?

Comment: Probably you get an object automatically constructed from JSON-string in your AJAX-callback. Try to use `ko.mapping.fromJS` instead.